# Looking for paper on species by Joyal

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request

I tried to Google this paper but cannot find it. And I don't know even its name. Please share how to look for it and other hidden papers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the paper you are talking about is [Une théorie combinatoire des séries formelles](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0001870881900529).

I knew the title, so it was easy to find. However, simply Googling "joyal species" gave me the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_species) and [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/species) pages for species, both of which cite the paper in their "References" section. In general, checking the bibliographies of related papers or Internet articles is helpful to track a paper.